# copy_to does not work with non-default schemas when trying to write permanent table

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr, dbplyr

I'm trying to use `copy_to` to write a table to SQL Server 2017 permanently (i.e. temporary = FALSE). It works on the default schema, but it does not work when I specify a schema other than the default schema. I get a curious error message:

`Error: <SQL> 'UPDATE STATISTICS EXISTING_SCHEMA.newTblIris'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Table 'newTblIris' does not exist.`

It is curious because it is obvious the table does not exist. I am trying to create the table.

```r
library(odbc)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL SERVER",
                 Server = "SERVER_NAME",
                 Database = "DB_NAME",
                 UID = "USER_ID",
                 PWD = "PASSWORD")

# works, can write this table to the default schema
copy_to(con, iris, "newTblIris", temporary = FALSE)

# successfully create temporary table in non-default schema
copy_to(con, iris, in_schema("EXISTING_SCHEMA", "newTblIris"))

# does not work and gives above error message
copy_to(con, iris, in_schema("EXISTING_SCHEMA", "newTblIris"), temporary = FALSE)
```

I have tried the "proper" way to write non-temporary tables following guidance from RStudio, https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/schema/#write-non-temporary-tables, however when I try their method I also get an error.

```r
dbWriteTable(con, SQL("EXISTING_SCHEMA.iris"), iris)
```

This gives an error `Error: Can't unquote EXISTING_SCHEMA.iris`

```r
- Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
 os       Windows Server >= 2012 x64  
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2019-03-05                  

- Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.0   2017-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 backports     1.1.3   2018-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 bit           1.1-14  2018-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 bit64         0.9-7   2017-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 blob          1.1.1   2018-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 callr         3.1.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 cli           1.0.1   2018-09-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 DBI         * 1.0.0   2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 dbplyr      * 1.3.0   2019-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 devtools      2.0.1   2018-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 dplyr       * 0.8.0.1 2019-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 fs            1.2.6   2018-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 glue          1.3.0   2018-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 hms           0.4.2   2018-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 odbc        * 1.1.6   2018-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 pillar        1.3.1   2018-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 pkgbuild      1.0.2   2018-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 pkgconfig     2.0.2   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 processx      3.2.1   2018-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 purrr         0.3.0   2019-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 Rcpp          1.0.0   2018-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 remotes       2.0.2   2018-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rlang         0.3.1   2019-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 tibble        2.0.1   2019-01-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 tidyselect    0.2.5   2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 usethis       1.4.0   2018-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
```

Comment: I assume you have to create the schema beforehand, can you confirm it does exist?

Comment: Correct. Schema exists, and I can confirm it does exist.

```r
# create schema
dbGetQuery(con, "CREATE SCHEMA EXISTING_SCHEMA")

# write a table to schema to confirm it exists
dbGetQuery(con , "CREATE TABLE EXISTING_SCHEMA.Region (Region_id int NOT NULL, Region_Name char(5) NOT NULL)")
```

Comment: the schema name is `r` or `EXISTING_SCHEMA`  ?  From your code above, it looks like it is the latter?

Comment: Sorry yes, It is EXISTING_SCHEMA.

Comment: I had to keep editing my comment to get the code to display properly.

Comment: For schema support, look into [DBI::Id()](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/91#issuecomment-371913101) which might be also available in `odbc` using latest GitHub development version (maybe now in CRAN version).

Comment: I've tried using DBI::Id(), and it works better, but there are still several annoying limitations. I posted another stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031149/issue-writing-to-non-default-schema-when-table-does-not-have-in-name, and I submitted an issue on Github: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/260

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem and developed the following work around. This is the core of a function I use to write R tables to the database (the full function can be found in my [dbplyr helpers repo](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers)). This cut down version assumes the table you are writing to already exists.

```
copy_r_to_sql = function(db_connection, schema, sql_table_name, r_table,
                         named_list_of_columns){

  # trim r table to just variables of interest
  r_table = r_table %>%
    select(names(named_list_of_columns))

  # if column type is character or date, wrap in single quotes
  # so SQL reads it as character string
  for(coln in colnames(r_table)){
    col_type = named_list_of_columns[[coln]]
    of(grepl("char", col_type) | grepl("date", col_type))
    r_table[coln] = apply(r_table[coln], 1, function(x) paste0("'", as.character(x), "'"))
  }

  # SQL
  sql_cols = paste0("([",paste0(names(named_list_of_columns), collapse = "],["), "])")
  sql_values = paste0(apply(r_table, 1, 
                            function(x) paste0("(", paste0(x, collapse = ","),")")),
                      collapse = ",\n")

  my_sql = build_sql(con = db_connection,
                     "INSERT INTO ", sql(schema), ".",sql(sql_table_name),"\n",
                     sql(sql_cols), "\n",
                     "VALUES ", sql(sql_values),";")

  result = dbExecute(db_connection, as.character(my_sql))
}
```

The function is designed to write the SQL text that would add the specified rows to your table. To understand what the function does you can replace the last line `dbExecute` with a print statement.

By way of an example function call:

```
named_list_of_columns = list(Sepal.Length = "[float](5,1) NOT NULL",
                             Sepal.Width = "[float](5,1) NOT NULL",
                             Species = "[varchar](15) NOT NULL")

copy_r_to_sql(con, "DB_NAME.SCHEMA", "newTblIris", iris, named_list_of_columns)
```

I have not tried using this for large tables. If you needed to load a large number of rows, I recommend creating a new table and appending to it in batches.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Could you provide a sample function call so I can get a better idea of what all the input parameters look like, so to speak?

Comment: Corrected & with a sample function call.

Comment: Interesting. It seems as if you literally turning the R data.frame into a string which could then be understood in SQL. Very cool. I posted similar (albeit different question) here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106088/sql-function-not-working-when-trying-to-write-table-to-non-default-schema), and you may be interested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should find success if you utilize `DBI::Id()` instead of `in_schema()`. For example, your last `copy_to()` example should work if changed to the following:

`copy_to(con, iris, DBI::Id(schema = "EXISTING_SCHEMA", table = "newTblIris"), temporary = FALSE)`

Just as an FYI, note that `DBI::Id()` requires that you explicitly name the `schema` and `table` arguments. You cannot simply pass the schema name and table name separated by commas in that order and rely on the implied order of the arguments like you can with most R functions. While `DBI::Id()` is ever so slightly more verbose to compose than `in_schema()` for that reason, I have found that tradeoff to be well worth it, as `DBI::Id()` just consistently works everywhere / exactly how I expect it to, whereas I have noticed somewhat surprising quirks similar to what you've detailed in your question in those areas when using `in_schema()`.

I know this question is fairly old at this point, but I just wanted to give my answer in hopes it might help someone quickly resolve their issue and adjust to a more robust alternative should anyone encounter something like this again.