# How to use dbWriteTable on a connection with no default Database

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, r-dbi

I've seen many posts on SO and the DBI Github regarding trouble using `DBI::dbWriteTable` (i.e. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106088/sql-function-not-working-when-trying-to-write-table-to-non-default-schema), [[2]](https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres/issues/179)). These mostly have to do with the use of non-default schemas or whatnot.

That's not my case.

I have a server running SQL Server 2014. This server contains multiple databases.

I'm developing a program which interacts with many of these databases at the same time. I therefore defined my connection using `DBI::dbConnect()` without a `Database=` argument.

I've so far only had to do SELECTs on the databases, and this connection works just fine with `dbGetQuery()`. I just need to name my tables including the database names: `DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar`, which is more than fine since it makes things transparent and intentional. It also stops me from being lazy and making some calls omitting the Database name on whichever DB I named in the connection.

I now need to add data to a table, and I can't get it to work. A call to

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn, "DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar", myData, append = TRUE)
```

works, but creates a table named `DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar` in the `master` Database, which isn't what I meant (I didn't even know there was a `master` Database).

The `DBI::dbWriteTable` man page states the name should be

> A character string specifying the unquoted DBMS table name, or the result of a call to `dbQuoteIdentifier()`.

So I tried `dbQuoteIdentifier()` (and a few other variations):

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn,
                  DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn,
                                         "DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar"),
                  myData)
# no error, same problem as above

DBI::dbWriteTable(conn,
                  DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn,
                                         DBI::SQL("DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar")),
                  myData)
# Error: Can't unquote DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar

DBI::dbWriteTable(conn,
                  DBI::SQL("DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar"),
                  myData)
# Error: Can't unquote DatabaseFoo.dbo.TableBar

DBI::dbWriteTable(conn,
                  DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn,
                                         DBI::Id(catalog = "DatabaseFoo",
                                                 schema = "dbo",
                                                 table = "TableBar")),
                  myData)
# Error: Can't unquote "DatabaseFoo"."dbo"."TableBar"

DBI::dbWriteTable(conn,
                  DBI::Id(catalog = "DatabaseFoo",
                          schema = "dbo",
                          table = "TableBar"),
                  myData)
# Error: Can't unquote "DatabaseFoo"."dbo"."TableBar"
```

In the `DBI::Id()` attempts, I also tried using `cluster` instead of `catalog`. No effect, identical error.

However, if I change my `dbConnect()` call to add a `Database="DatabaseFoo"` argument, I can simply use `dbWriteTable(conn, "TableBar", myData)` and it works.

So the question becomes, am I doing something wrong? Is this related to the problems in the other questions?

Comment: This looks like a problem that's fixed in the dev version of DBI, can you please try installing from GitHub and double-check?

Comment: @krlmlr Indeed, installing the dev version works. Feel free to write an answer for a free checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shortcoming in the DBI package. The dev version DBI >= 1.0.0.9002 no longer suffers from this problem, will hit CRAN as DBI 1.1.0 soonish.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: Do you see exactly the same symptoms?

Comment: DBI not uses the default schema and adds the new table prepending my domain name and username. I ended up using `DBI::Id`.